# Should I open a US bank account for my study abroad?

Tags: usa, united-kingdom, banking, uk-citizens, money-transfer

I am going to start a year's study in the US, transferring from the UK. I will be staying in San Diego, CA.

In the UK, I currently have a student account with Santander and a general account with HSBC. Ideally, I'd like to use my student account while abroad but fear that I will run into too many costs, such as transfer fees and conversion costs etc.

Would opening a bank account in the US and transferring my money in bulk be beneficial, or would I be better off using my English bank accounts?

I have also heard of an international debit card service that companies like the Post Office run but since seeing the [failure that is the Travel Money card](http://www.reviewcentre.com/reviews108401.html), I'm sceptical. Any thoughts on this?

---

Note that this is a post migration from [this post](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/54034/should-i-open-a-us-bank-account-for-my-study-abroad) on Travel SE, which was put on hold due to irrelevancy to that site.

Comment: Did you try asking HSBC what they'd charge you for a USD account based in the UK?

Comment: You could probably get away with a dollar account outside the US but it would be much more convenient to have a US account.

Comment: @Karlson If the OP isn't receiving any money in the USA, just transfering over their UK funds, what would a USA-based USD account offer them over a London-based USD account? (Other than significantly weaker consumer protection....)

Comment: @Gagravarr ease of paying bills and which consumer protection would they lose?

Comment: @Karlson In the UK, it's almost impossible to withdraw money from someone's account with just the account details, and if you sign up to a Direct Debit to take a bill and they make a mistake, the money is returned to you instantly by your bank. I gather it's much easier for other people/companies to withdraw money from your account in the USA, and if they withdraw the wrong amount it isn't your bank that normally fixes it for you

Comment: @Gagravarr They can.  You'll just have to dispute it and show that the amount is wrong.

Comment: HSBC would allow me to open an overseas account, which has a £5/month fee (as far as I can tell.) However, I'm now considering simply getting an international credit card and using that instead, as suggested on [this Money Saving Expert article](http://www.moneysavingexpert.com/credit-cards/travel-credit-cards#halifax).

Comment: @Karlson In the UK, you just ring up / visit your bank, tell them that the DD was wrong, and they'll refund you the money on the spot, no need to show/prove anything. (The company you were paying will still want the right/correct amount, but that's between you and them)

Comment: @Gagravarr Some US banks let you do this too.  All Credit Cards do.  Now as far as bills with direct debit you may need a copy of a bill to send forward them but that's about all you need to do.

Answer (score 2):

There are **odd benefits** to having a bank account and a US address - especially if you are, say, purchasing computer parts from newegg.com, buying music from itunes - what you can buy or rent depends on the licensing agreements for each country and believe me when I tell you that the US offerings are very different (Better) than what Canadians can buy on itunes or even netflix. Same thing when using Amazon.

Each company has its rules for transactions, and some do not like it when your billing address is in a different country than your shipping address.

As an American married to a Canadian, and one who spends A LOT of time in Canada each year, I like the ability having a US bank card (debit) so that I can continue using Netflix (with a VPN) while in Canada.

FWIW, I have found Charles Schwab bank (even though it's primarily an investment company) to offer the best services from any other bank. They don't charge for debit card use ever and will refund you the fees each ATM machine charges.  Plus their currency conversion rates much higher than US banks. But this last point might be moot since you'd be converting into USD.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. How does it work when you transfer money into the USD account from your CAD account? Are there additional fees like conversion fees?